# Readjust colobar limits (caxis) on image with true colors CData

Tags: image, matlab, colorbar

I need to display a true color image, got with `imread` and shown with `imshow`, along with a (apparently) unrelated colorbar. I'm calling:

```
figure
imshow(my_image)
colorbar
colormap(cool(200));
caxis([0 15]);
```

Using a test image, it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see `caxis` has no effect on the colorbar. Colorbar max value will stay `200`, which is the number of rows in my colormap. That's properly described by the documentation of `caxis`, that says:

> It does not affect surfaces, patches, or images with true color CData or with CDataMapping set to direct.

Is there any workaround?
I tried some weird stuff like subplotting the image on one side and the colorbar on the other (but I get a blank plot on this second side, and so much blank space out); I tried plotting `zeros`, then `colorbar` and `caxis`, then replacing the zeros plot with `imshow` (but colorbar gets refreshed accordingly). Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a normal behavior, as you noticed in the documentation.

True color images have three channels, and a colormap only one channel ... so what you want to do is similar to mapping 3d data on a single axis. There is an indetermination and Matlab doesn't know how to handle this, so it simply does not handle it at all.

The only workaround I see is to reduce your data to a single channel,  for instance with `rgb2gray`. Colormaps work great with grayscale images.

**Edit**

If you want to keep the image in true color and an unrelated colormap, there are a few solutions.

Please note that on my computer (R2015a, Ubuntu) the code you posted works, *i.e.* the colorbar axis is mapped to [0 15] after `caxis([0 15])`. Maybe an upgrade to a more recent release would fix your problem.

This being said, as you say that it does not work with your version, you can still modify the labels of the colorbar ticks to make them look like what you want:

```
hcb = colorbar;
set(hcb,'YTick',linspace(1,200,4));
set(hcb,'YTickLabel',linspace(0,15,4));
```

... but this is both a very ugly workaround and a quite dangerous practice.

Best,

Comment: I see. But what if I need the image as is, with original colors, and an unrelated colorbar? How could that be done? (best thing that comes to my mind is subplotting..)

Comment: No luck for me on R2014a. Will try your workaround as soon as possible, thank you.

Comment: Works great. Why is it dangerous?

Comment: It is dangerous to display a colorbar that is completely unrelated to the plot nearby. If there is a mistake somewhere, the end user can be very easily fooled.

Comment: Thank you (actually it's not unrelated, I'm coloring the image according to *200*, *15* and other stuff. But yeah, it's un-linked).

Comment: I noticed you can have a better "ticking" using, in this case, `set(hcb,'YTick',linspace(0,200,4)-0.5)` (starting from 0 and subtracting 0.5). This way ticks and labels fit the bar from top to bottom. If this is legit (i.e., no conceptual errors), you might want to edit your answer. Starting from 1 as you said, the higher label is always hidden.